# Annotation PreAuthorize is not working with Jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jersey

I am creating a book store application using Jersey and Spring Boot. I have implemented Spring Security in the application. Now, I want to restrict methods. I want some methods to be used by admin only and not by any normal user. So, I am using @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")  for that but it is not working. Pleae help!

Controller Interface

```
@Path("/api/bookstoreapp/books")
public interface BookController {


@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("")
public BookResourceRto createBook(BookResourceRto book);

@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")  
public List<BookResourceRto> getAllBooks();

/**
 * Method to search book from database using the search keyword
 * 
 * @param searchKeyword some information about the book from the following -
 *                      name/author/description/ISBN number
 * @return searched book
 */
@GET
@Path("/nameorauthorordesc")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<BookResourceRto> getFilteredBooks(@QueryParam("name") String name, 
@QueryParam("author") String author,
        @QueryParam("description") String description);

}
```

SecurityConfig Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled= true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/generate- 
         token").permitAll()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
       .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Check JWT authentication token before any request
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

 }
```

Please tell how can I make @PreAuthorize work in jersey, or I am doing something wrong or is there any other method for this?

Comment: This configuration looks good to me. Try to use hasAuthority('ADMIN')

Comment: @Nemanja Yes, I tried this but didn't work

Comment: What roles/authorities does your user have? Can you post how your user looks like?

Comment: @PalakKharbanda Is your implementation of your controller in the Spring context? See https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-rest-api-with-spring